# How to calculate percentage in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, I have this database containing some online articles, their titles, their authors, and a log history that contains how many people logged into the website to read which article and when.

The data base has 3 tables
**Authors table, with columns:**
names, bio, ID(author's id)

**Articles table with columns:**
author (has the values of ID from table authors), title, slug, lead, time, body, id(article's id)

**Log table, with columns:**
Path, IP, method, status, time, ID(user's id)

It is required to ***determine on which days did more than 1% of requests lead to errors?***
This is determined through columns: **time and status** from table log, the status column contains either the value: **OK** to indicate that the web page loaded successfully, or the value: **404 not found** to indicate an unsuccessful log.

I tried coming up with the following solution:

```py
select time::DATE, 100.*count(status)/(select count(*) from log) as error 
from log 
where log.status ='404 NOT FOUND' 
group by time::DATE;
```

but it gave me a table full of zeros.
Can anyone help me calculate the right percentage?

Comment: I assume Postgres because of the `::` cast and add the tag for you. If I'm not correct please change the tag to the actual DBMS you're using.

Comment: You are correct it is Postgres, i forgot to add it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use conditional aggregation in a `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT time::date,
       count(CASE
               WHEN status = '404 NOT FOUND' THEN
                 1
             END)::decimal
       / count(*)
       * 100 error
       FROM log
       GROUP BY time::date
       HAVING count(CASE
                      WHEN status = '404 NOT FOUND' THEN
                        1
                    END)::decimal
              / count(*)
              * 100
              > 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a version greater than 9.4 this could be done using the [FILTER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) clause, just remember to cast your counts to a float or numeric `::real`, `::double precision`, `::numeric`

```
SELECT
    time::date,
    count(*) as total,
    (
        count(status) filter (where log.status = '404 NOT FOUND') /
        count(*)::real
    ) * 100 as error
FROM log
GROUP BY time::date
HAVING count(*) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write this as:

```
select time::DATE,
       avg( (status = '404 NOT FOUND')::int ) as not_found_ratio
group by time::DATE
having not_found_ratio > 0.01;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to cast the COUNT() functions as DECIMAL. COUNT() returns as INT and therefore won't have the decimal component necessary to calculate the percentage.